# GruntJS and imagemin, Is it ok to overwrite 'src'?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I have a grunt script (written by someone else) which is minify'ing images, but the the source and destination are the same folder, which to my mind appears to be overwriting the source with the minified images.

Here is a section from the gruntfile.js

```
imagemin: {
      options: {
        compress: true
      },
      dist   : {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd   : 'templates',
            src   : ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
            dest  : 'templates'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

There is also a 'watch' task and 'newer' is in use so files are not reprocessed.

Is this ok? Or should the source and destination always be different? I don't think 'jpg' and 'gif' come in a 'lossless' flavour. I've been told that because the script is using 'newer', it keeps a cache of what it's done that survives a restart.

Comment: Yes, it's ok, it works.  I have a similar task that's run before I release my project to optimize svg files that may have been added to the project since the previous release.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a horrible idea. (I mean that it's written to overwrite the same directory, that's insane!)

You can definitely change src to `src: ['large/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],` and drop the original images there.

`newer` will still keep track of which files have already been compressed, but you'll still have access to the original high-res images in a separate `large` folder.

MORE:

Though in my own projects, I have a `src` folder at the top-level directory for the project, so `src/img/**/*` is compressed and output to just `img`. It's a complete split between the source files that all go in a top-level `src` directory, and production ready is everything but `src` at the top for static sites, or in a `dest/build/whatever` directory for more involved projects at the top.